# Extract certain values from different columns in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet and I want to extract different values from different columns into a single columns.

[desired excel sheet format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xufpr.png)

I want to figure out first of all how to deal with subheaders like `astro` and `athens grey` as well as to extract information in this patterns. Thanks

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk6Lw.png)

I have managed to resolve the sub header issue , Now i just want help with regex to extract information in desired format.
Here is what I have done so far ,[Subheaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap5gZ.png)

Comment: Please provide a sample expected output. Also, can you share your data?

Comment: @keramat I have attached a sample output.

Comment: I do not know the exact format of your headers. So upload a sample file with just a few rows.

Comment: ok do check now

Comment: Where is the xlsx file?

Comment: I attached all the pictures. I cannot attach the data

Comment: As I said I can not infer the kind of header you mean watching photos. You can replace the real values with some similar ones. Also, I need just some rows to be included in the excel file not the whole file.

Comment: i attached it now.i know regex will be used but i can't come up with the required expression for this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if it helps:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('Sample.xlsx')
data[data.isna().sum(axis=1)==6]
data = data.dropna(how='all')
import numpy as np
data['SKU'].astype(str).str.extract('([^\(\)]*)')[0].str.strip().replace('\d+', np.nan, regex = True).fillna(method='ffill')+' '+data['DESCRIPTION']+' '+data['SIZE'].str.extract('([^0-9x]+)').fillna('')[0]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: pls see the edit. Can you help me with the concatenation? I have resolved the sub header issue.

Comment: Look at the answer now.

Comment: The last line gives an error "ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types"

Comment: It is related to content of your file. In my data sample it works.

Comment: Maybe there are some values with different types in your columns. Try .astype(str) on the columns you are concatenating.

Comment: Also, as you can see the last line contains multiple parts. So, first check the error is from which part by commenting all parts but one every time.

Comment: It works thanks!! but there is a slight problem , I dont want information in brakets to be included as well. I just want the text other than digits and brackets like ATHENS GREY (exclude info) SLABS - POLISHED CALL TO CHECK SIZE